# Bound a norm $L^{2}$

Tags: lp-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let $f \in L^{2}(-1,1)$ and $g \in L^{\infty}(-1,1)$ such that $g(x) \geq 0$, $\forall x \in [-1,1]$ and $g (x) > 0$, $\forall x \in [0,1]$.

If
$$ 
\|g^{\frac{1}{2}}f\|_{L^{2}(-1,1)} \leq C_{1}
$$
where $C_{1} >0$. Can I limit the norm $L^{2}(-1,1)$ of the function $f$? That is, I can show that there is $C_{2} > 0$ so that
$$
\|f\|_{L^{2}(-1,1)} \leq C_{2} ?
$$

Comment: @geetha290krm [0,1]. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let $g(x)=|x|$ if $x \neq 0$ and $g(0)=1$. Let $f=g^{-1/2}$. Can you check that this is a counter-example?

Comment: $\|f\|_{L^{2}(-1,1)}^{2} = \text{sgn}(x)\log(x)\bigg|_{-1}^{1}$.

Comment: $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac 1 {|x|}dx=\infty$.  @Andrémash

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you agree that $\int_{-1}^1\frac 1 {|x|}dx \geq \int_{0}^1\frac 1 {|x|}dx=\int_{0}^1\frac 1 {x}dx$? @Andrémash

Comment: I agree yes. I understood